# Problem installing pandas on shared hosting

Tags: python, pandas, linux, numpy, shared-hosting

I am using shared hosting on **Namecheap** and I am trying to run my django application that requires pandas for some data manipulation.

I am using a virtual environment on a Linux server with **python 3.9.16** installed.

The
`Original error was: /tmp/pip-build-env-z2e3yd98/overlay/lib64/python3.9/site-packages/numpy/core/_multiarray_umath.cpython-39-x86_64-linux-gnu.so: failed to map segment from shared object: Operation not permitted`

I tried to run `pip install pandas` and got the following error:

```
Collecting pandas  Using cached pandas-2.0.3.tar.gz (5.3 MB)
  Installing build dependencies ... done
  Getting requirements to build wheel ... error
  error: subprocess-exited-with-error

  × Getting requirements to build wheel did not run successfully.
  │ exit code: 1
  ╰─> [53 lines of output]
      Traceback (most recent call last):
        File "/tmp/pip-build-env-z2e3yd98/overlay/lib64/python3.9/site-packages/numpy/core/__init__.py", line 22, in <module>
          from . import multiarray
        File "/tmp/pip-build-env-z2e3yd98/overlay/lib64/python3.9/site-packages/numpy/core/multiarray.py", line 12, in <module>
          from . import overrides
        File "/tmp/pip-build-env-z2e3yd98/overlay/lib64/python3.9/site-packages/numpy/core/overrides.py", line 7, in <module>
          from numpy.core._multiarray_umath import (
      ImportError: /tmp/pip-build-env-z2e3yd98/overlay/lib64/python3.9/site-packages/numpy/core/_multiarray_umath.cpython-39-x86_64-linux-gnu.so: failed to map segment from shared object: Operation not permitted

      During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

      Traceback (most recent call last):
        File "/home/phutggts/virtualenv/dashboard.phuthalichaba.com/3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pip/_vendor/pyproject_hooks/_in_process/_in_process.py", line 353, in <module>
          main()
        File "/home/phutggts/virtualenv/dashboard.phuthalichaba.com/3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pip/_vendor/pyproject_hooks/_in_process/_in_process.py", line 335, in main
          json_out['return_val'] = hook(**hook_input['kwargs'])
        File "/home/phutggts/virtualenv/dashboard.phuthalichaba.com/3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pip/_vendor/pyproject_hooks/_in_process/_in_process.py", line 118, in get_requires_for_build_wheel
          return hook(config_settings)
        File "/tmp/pip-build-env-z2e3yd98/overlay/lib/python3.9/site-packages/setuptools/build_meta.py", line 341, in get_requires_for_build_wheel
          return self._get_build_requires(config_settings, requirements=['wheel'])
        File "/tmp/pip-build-env-z2e3yd98/overlay/lib/python3.9/site-packages/setuptools/build_meta.py", line 323, in _get_build_requires
          self.run_setup()
        File "/tmp/pip-build-env-z2e3yd98/overlay/lib/python3.9/site-packages/setuptools/build_meta.py", line 487, in run_setup
          super(_BuildMetaLegacyBackend,
        File "/tmp/pip-build-env-z2e3yd98/overlay/lib/python3.9/site-packages/setuptools/build_meta.py", line 338, in run_setup
          exec(code, locals())
        File "<string>", line 18, in <module>
        File "/tmp/pip-build-env-z2e3yd98/overlay/lib64/python3.9/site-packages/numpy/__init__.py", line 140, in <module>
          from . import core
        File "/tmp/pip-build-env-z2e3yd98/overlay/lib64/python3.9/site-packages/numpy/core/__init__.py", line 48, in <module>
          raise ImportError(msg)
      ImportError:

      IMPORTANT: PLEASE READ THIS FOR ADVICE ON HOW TO SOLVE THIS ISSUE!

      Importing the numpy C-extensions failed. This error can happen for
      many reasons, often due to issues with your setup or how NumPy was
      installed.

      We have compiled some common reasons and troubleshooting tips at:

          https://numpy.org/devdocs/user/troubleshooting-importerror.html

      Please note and check the following:

        * The Python version is: Python3.9 from "/home/phutggts/virtualenv/dashboard.phuthalichaba.com/3.9/bin/python3.9_bin"
        * The NumPy version is: "1.19.3"

      and make sure that they are the versions you expect.
      Please carefully study the documentation linked above for further help.

      Original error was: /tmp/pip-build-env-z2e3yd98/overlay/lib64/python3.9/site-packages/numpy/core/_multiarray_umath.cpython-39-x86_64-linux-gnu.so: failed to map segment from shared object: Operation not permitted

      [end of output]

  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
error: subprocess-exited-with-error

× Getting requirements to build wheel did not run successfully.
│ exit code: 1
╰─> See above for output.

note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
```

Comment: Did you manage to solve this? I am having the same issue.